# Wordpress with my site

Tags: wordpress, apache

I have a blog on wordpress, for example www/blog.com - folder
and my site example.com, www/example.com - folder.

I try integrate worpress with my site. **example.com/blog** - must go to wordpress index page, and **example.com/blog/post_name** must go to wordpress post.

apache conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    Alias /blog /var/www/blog.com
    <Location /blog>
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
<Directory /var/www/example.com>
    #code
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/blog.com>
    #code
</Directory>
```

In worpress admin panel i change: 
**WordPress Address (URL)** to *example.com/blog*
**Site Address (URL)** to *example.com*
**Permalink Settings** to /blog/%postname%/

When i go to *example.com/blog* it work fine, but when i type 
*example.com/blog/post_name* i have 404 error.

**Edit:**
request **example.com/blog** go to wordpress directory, but **example.com/blog/post_name** go to example.com index.php

Comment: sounds like you need to enable mod_rewrite. what version of apache are you running?

Comment: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out this [wordpress.org article](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Using_.22Pretty.22_permalinks). it will help you ensure that you have mod_rewrite enabled, along with inserting the `AllowOverride FileInfo` directive that I can already see you're missing within your `VirtualHost`. Don't forget to read on about the .htaccess file for your /blog (/var/www/blog.com) directory. You'll want to make sure your `RewriteBase` is set to `/blog`

Comment: @Marvin glad this worked...would you mind accepting my answer please (: